# Crafter CMS - how to unpublish (take offline) a page?

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

It is possible to unpublish a page (take it offline) in Crafter CMS? The word unpublish is never used in the docs, and I looked around and tried some things in the interface, but nothing is obvious.
I don't want to delete the page, I just want take it offline so it can be edited and published again at some later time.

The is a very common operation and it seems like really basic CMS functionality. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `disabled` flag. Please see the docs: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/content-modeling.html?highlight=disabled#form-control-variable-names

While modeling your content, add the `disabled` meta-data field and the content authors can then disable a content item. This also removes the item from search, as you'd expect.

There is an open bug for the API getTree where is doesn't respect the `disabled` flag, you can track it here: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1326